# Merging pdfs by directory/folder

Tags: python

I have a folder('a') of folders('b'). Each folder in 'b' is named after the contract it covers. Within each folder in b are the main contract document and modifications for that contract. All the docs are pdfs. I wrote code to merge pdfs by contract.

The problem is the code is not breaking up the pdfs correctly. The first output has only info for contract 1; the second output has info for contract 1 and 2; the third contract has info for contracts 1, 2, and 3. I tried strategically placing a line of code to clear the storage device but the code is still not acting right.

```
root_folder = r"./RawContracts"

x = [a for a in os.listdir(root_folder) if not a.endswith(".pdf")]
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for folder in x:
    house = root_folder + "/" + folder
    x2 = [root_folder+"/"+folder+"/"+a for a in os.listdir(house) if a.endswith(".pdf")]
    for pdf in x2:
        merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
    with open("%s.pdf" % folder, "wb") as fout:
        merger.write(fout)
    x2 = []
```

I cobbled this solution together after referencing many different sites. The "x2 = []" at the end of the second for loop is my attempt at solving the problem. It does not work. Thanks in advance for your help.

A little more detail on the problem.

Let's say contract1 folder contains 2 seperate pdfs(each with 1 page) pertaining to contract1:
pdf1 = "4 computers for $1000"
pdf2 = "Mod1: 3 computers @ $825; 4 @ $1000 canceled"

contract2 folder contains 2 separate pdfs(each with 1 page) pertaining to contract2:
pdf1 = "5 widgets for $45"
pdf2 = "exercise option 3 not option 2"

Desired output:

1 merged pdf named contract1.pdf containing contract1_pdf1 and contract1_pdf2
1 merged pdf named contract2.pdf containing contract2_pdf1 and contract2_pdf2

current output:

1 pdf with contents of contract1 folder correctly merged
1 pdf with contents of contract1 folder merged with contents of contract2 folder. This folder should only have contract 2 stuff.

I need python to discard from its memory everything dealing with contract1 once it has completed that part of the loop.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how the code is not working? Eg. Error codes, expected output, etc. This would help us figure out what is going on with the code.

Comment: There are no errors. The code works it's just not doing what I want. It's not separating the contracts into their own pdf. The first contract in a is in its own pdf. But the second output includes contract 1 details again along with the contents of contract 2. I need to loop to cleanse itself and start over after looking at a contract folder.

Comment: I suspect in this case it's hitting each file more than once, I will test your code and see what I can do to help, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code using .txt to test, it seems like the issue might be with your `merger` object. It seems that in your loop, you do `merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))` for every file in the loop, but at the beginning of each loop, you do not clear the `merger`.

Eg. if I had a folder structure like so:

[image]

My merger, if it were like a list, would end up like this with the 3 merges:

> ['./randomtextfolder/1/1_1.txt', './randomtextfolder/1/1_2.txt']
>
> ['./randomtextfolder/1/1_1.txt', './randomtextfolder/1/1_2.txt', './randomtextfolder/2/2_1.txt', './randomtextfolder/2/2_2.txt']
>
> ['./randomtextfolder/1/1_1.txt', './randomtextfolder/1/1_2.txt', './randomtextfolder/2/2_1.txt', './randomtextfolder/2/2_2.txt', './randomtextfolder/3/3_1.txt']

---

I am unsure how you would clear the merger variable, but I suspect the line `merger = PdfFileMerger()` placed after your first for loop would be good.

Your code would look like so:

```
root_folder = r"./RawContracts"

x = [a for a in os.listdir(root_folder) if not a.endswith(".pdf")]


for folder in x:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    house = root_folder + "/" + folder
    # note that we removed x2 = [], because the following line re-sets x2 anyway
    x2 = [root_folder+"/"+folder+"/"+a for a in os.listdir(house) if a.endswith(".pdf")]
    for pdf in x2:
        merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
    with open("%s.pdf" % folder, "wb") as fout:
        merger.write(fout)
```

If this does not work as intended, you can try `merger.close()` to see if that wipes the merger memory, as indicated in [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html) documentation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @wolf7687 no problem! Glad that I could help :)